# npm install not working it showing npm packages are looking for funding - react native

Tags: react-native, npm, npm-install

[image: error-log]

I usually get

> **n** packages are looking for funding.

When running `npm install` on a react project. Any idea what that means?

Answer (score 4):

You can  disabled it  using: `npm install --no-fund`

[npm blog](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/188841555980/updates-to-community-docs-more)

> As of npm v6.13 we’ve added support for a brand new funding field in package.json along with a corresponding npm fund sub-command.

> Post install you will now see output that describes the number of packages that have defined funding information. You can opt-out of this prompt by using the --no-fund flag if you so choose.

> At the end of August, we made a promise to the community to invest time & effort to better support package maintainers. This work is just the first, small step toward creating a means/mechanism for a more sustainable open source development ecosystem.

[link](https://dev.to/ruyadorno/npm-6-13-0-7f3)

> And the second new feature we shipped in this version is the work I've put together to support a new funding property in package.json - in a bid to help the open source community npm decided to add a new command:
> npm fund that will provide more visibility to npm users on what dependencies are actively looking for ways to fund their work.

> As part of that change, npm install will also show a single message at the end in order to let the user aware that dependencies are looking for funding, it looks like this:``

```
$ npm install
3 packages are looking for funding.
Run "npm fund" to find out more.
```

Answer (score 4):

While supporting projects is a good thing - in operational/logging contexts this donationware postinstall output is annoying and cluttering.

The message can be disabled using:
`npm install --no-fund`